# Vhdl vector boundry check

Tags: vhdl, sequential

```
type dmemSpace is array(0 to 1023) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal dataMem : dmemSpace := ( 
  400 => X"00000000",
  404 => X"00001000",
  408 => X"FFFFEFFF",
  others => X"00000000"
);

signal dAddr : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal check : integer; 


dAddr(31 downto 0) <= Addr(31 downto 2) & "00";  
check <= to_integer(unsigned(dAddr));
DataOut <= dataMem(to_integer(unsigned(dAddr))) when (check > 0);
```

Its me again.... In working on a  single cycle cpu and everything else works fine but this particular line in the memory.

```
DataOut <= dataMem(to_integer(unsigned(dAddr))) when (check > 0);
```

I want to prevent an index out of bounds error for DataOut but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

- `Check > 0` prevents all data from coming out.
- `Check >= 0` lets the error through... when the index that causes the exception is -4.

Comment: Is this within a clocked process? If it is, it is a scheduling issue. If it is not, you have created a latch with DataOut. Why aren't you just using 9 downto 0 of `dAddr` to limit to 1023? (I know, could be a learning exercise.)

Comment: ! YOURE RIGHT I added it to the clock process and everything is fine now. Thanks for everything. Actually this has been bothering me for says now.... I'm such a scrub <.<

Comment: Then why did you "accept" the answer below that made no sense? I added an answer that included some of this and a few other warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have it in a process, you need "`dAddr`" and "`check`" to be variables, or else you are taking two clock cycles based on whether or not the previous address was valid, not the one you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If your memory has 1024 locations, your address should be 10 bits, not the 32 bits you have now. If your address is `unsigned(9 downto 0)`, all of its values are legal input for your memory array.

*Note* you put data at address 400, 404, 408. You are leaving three blank spaces in between each data element! Even though your data is 4 bytes wide, every address takes up an entire 4 byte data word.

Answer (score -1):

A few other problems with this attempt and the provided answers:
You could not have applied index of -4.  Your dAddr is type std_logic_vector cast to UNSIGNED.  So it is always a positive or ZERO.
Using VARIABLES is a solution if you are just SIMULATING.  For SYNTHESIS they still need to be SIGNALS if you want to know what the implementation is doing. 
Your memory is Read only.  If you want to have read/write memory you will want to have this in a clocked process so you generate REGISTERS instead of LATCHES.
I dont know WHAT you're doing with the array partial assignment in the declaration.  Yes it is syntatically correct, but assignment at declaration DOES NOT APPLY TO SYNTHESIZED logic.  This really only works for CONSTANTS (in all fairness, that is what your dataMem signal is.... a constant.)
To initialize the memory you need it in the RESET block of your clocked process, use a for loop to set all to x"00", followed by the 3 assignments for 400, 404, 408 using [dataMem(404) <= x"08";]
Assign DataOut EVERY clock
  if (check < 1024) then 
    DataOut <= dataMem(check);
  else
    DataOut <= (others => "0"); -- maybe? or just retain old value?
  end if;